# CSS make header fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a web page which contains an HTML table. The table is longer than the size of the page, so user has to scroll down the page to view the complete table.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th></th><th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want that, when the user scroll down the page & as the table header disappears, it should get fixed on its place, so that user can view the particular column value with its header.

Is it possible to have fixed header when the user scrolls up ?

Comment: I recommend you to check out jquery datatables plugin for every table task. Datatables.net is its address. It has every feature I needed on a table since now.

Comment: you can use various jQuery plugins like...    [floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/)  or [fixedheadertable](http://www.fixedheadertable.com/)